# How to create a view with aggregate Drupal 7

Tags: views, entities, feeds

I am creating a view about quantity of articles sold and I would like aggregate by years and month for each article.

An example

|............|..........Year..........|..........Year..........|
|............|Jan|Feb|.....|Dec|.............................|
|Article..|Σquantity|Σ(price*quantity)
|Article..|Σquantity|Σ(price*quantity)

For each order I have the quantity of article sold and the order date.

But I don't know how I can do that.

Thanks for your help.